# Call a model function when CodeIgniter loads

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I've been working on a CI application and I came across an issue.

Instead of using a CronJob, I want to acomplish the following:

normally, when a user opens my website CodeIgniter loads in the background. When CI finishes loading I want to call a function from a model that I've written. How can I acomplish this?

(I don't know which controller would be loaded by the viewer, hence my confusion)

Hopefully you understood me and I'm awaiting your answers

Comment: 1. do you want it to run when a user visits home page or for all the pages?
2. do you want it to run just for once or for everytime a page loads?

Comment: I want it to run when a user loads any of the pages. I can do this by calling the function in every single controller file but I'm wondering if there's a way to avoid this and do it on another way.

Comment: The perfect goal would be running the function once a day, but since this's impossible without a scheduled task or a cron, I want to run it every time CodeIgniter is loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you read about **[Hooks](https://ellislab.com/codeigniter/user-guide/general/hooks.html)** in CodeIgniter. You can specify at what point in the application you want the hook to run, and from what you describe the `post_system` hook is what you need.

> **post_system**
>   Called after the final rendered page is sent to the browser, at the end of system execution after the finalized data is sent to the browser.

In the hook definition you specify what class and method to run.

```
$hook['pre_controller'] = array(
                                'class'    => 'MyClass',
                                'function' => 'Myfunction',
                                'filename' => 'Myclass.php',
                                'filepath' => 'hooks',
                                'params'   => array('beer', 'wine', 'snacks')
                                );
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!